# How Data Access Layer communicates with Presentation Layer in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

Im new to OOP & PHP. After being fed-up of "Person's Class-Object examples", I want to know exactly how a function would return a set of rows from database to the presentation layer in a way that:

- Conditions and validations are managed by Business Layer's function
  (e.g. getEmployees($DepartmentID)).
- All HTM, CSS and Javascripts are looked after by Presentation layer.

Comment: What language(s) are you coming from? What are "Person's Class-Object examples"?

Answer (score 1):

First all you need to create a frontend(client side) for the backend(server side), in the BL you have getEmployees, i dont now wich king of output is , but if is a webservice you need to translate to xml or json response, if is normal you need to create html markup.

my recomendation: create a BL OOP PHP Webservice, and from the Pre. Layer use some free JS CLIENT FRAMEWORK, like smartgwt,jqery,etc